# Why do i get a Whitelabel Error Page with the same jsp file in a new project?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new on spring-boot. I have an error when I start my spring-boot application on the port 8080. I get `Whitelabel` Error Page.

I have created a very simple `.jsp` file in `\src\main\resources\META-INF\resources\WEB-INF\jsp`.

Here is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.stl.saar.internetentw2</groupId>
<artifactId>1-SpringBootJsp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>SpringBootJsp</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-jar-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.5,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>jar</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

Here is the controller of my application

```
@Controller
public class ZooController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

The har file that should be return is this

```
<%@page import="java.time.LocalDate"%>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <h3>Date: <%= LocalDate.now() %></h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

The main application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyZooApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyZooApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here my application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I have tried to run this in other project. In the other project works fine, but it doesn´t work in this project.

[I have to use this folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbSby.png)

Comment: you are using spring boot. Create a "static" or "public" folder in the resources folder and place your `index.jsp` file there.

Comment: so a new "static" folder in the main resources folder, or a "static" folder in the META-INF\resources\ folder? i already have a static folder in resources for images. in which path do i enter in application.properties?

Comment: `static` in the main/resources folder. You don't have to enter a path in `application.properties` - that's the beauty of SB. Everything in `resources/static/` will automatically be moved into META-INF for you. Including your `main/resources/jsp` folder.

Comment: ok thanks. but it still doesn´t work. "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp"

Comment: this project structure should be already finished. so i just should implement the web application and shouldn´t create new folders or anything.

Comment: i also have images in the static folder. i have to implement the images in jsp before he can find my jsp file? I can not get ahead

Comment: Read this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: Springboot usually has some troubles when it comes to jar packaging and jsp , so try using war as packaging instead of jar. For your configuration everything should work properly but still.